# How do you draw a circle around something?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using html, css, javascript and jQuery, I would like to present the user with a paragraph with the directions: "Read the story.  Then, circle all the nouns."

Q: How would I draw a circle around a word when the user clicks on it?
It's ok if every word has to be in its own span tag.

Comment: isn't it a lot easer to ask the user to "Underline all the nouns"...

Comment: Good comment.  I guess I'm just not thinking creatively.  But it would be neat to show a circle slowly (1 second) being drawn around the word though.

Comment: Yes, I agree that would be neat indeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the following HTML:

```
<p id="circleNouns">Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</p>
```

First, let's wrap each word of the text in `<span>` tags with jQuery:

```
var $cn = $('#circleNouns'),
    cnText = $cn.text();
cnText = cnText.replace(/\s/g, '</span> <span>');
$cn.html('<span>' + cnText + '</span>');
```

Then if we style a class to draw a circle like border:

```
.selected { 
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
}
```

We can simply add the following click event:

```
$cn.find('span').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Then however the page is submitted you can check `$cn.find('.selected')` each `.html()` against your list of nouns to see if the answers are correct.

[**Here's a working example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/uJc6Y/2/)

Comment: Wow mVChr!  I'm going to study all the answers you've given on Stackoverflow because you are that good.  I really appreciate this answer.

Comment: Haha, thank you.  If you're interested in getting better at Javascript and jQuery I learned a lot from jAndy's answers too.

Comment: This is very old, but I like this answer and want to make one small improvement: adding `margin: 0px -1px;` to the `.selected` class will avoid the movement of text once the border circles are drawn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transparent PNGs of different sizes, small, medium, large to circle different sizes of words.

So when the user clicks the span/div , use javascript to overlay that PNG on the word, and resize it to best size dynamically.

But I would still suggest why not use a simple HTML based border to mark it ? It can be a border with rounded edges with minor css to make it more fancy

Comment: Oh yeah!  I could use the border-radius css.  That's a good idea!

Comment: Yeah you can, hope you would not want IE6 users to take your grammar test, IE6 already reflects a lot bout them